# Does TLS encrypt each packets separately?

Tags: ssl, tls1.2, network-protocols

When encrypting with TLS, do we encrypt the whole data-block we want to send, and then divided it up into packets, or do we encrypt each packet separately? And if so, can packets be decrypted independently?

Comment: Every time you write to TLS a new TLS Record is created and encrypted,  and then segmented by TCP and packetised by IP.

Comment: So you have to collect all the packets before being able to decrypt the message, is that correct? Or can you do partial decryption on the go?

Comment: Good question. I imagine TLS needs the entire record so its HMAC can be checked before any of it can be released to the application.

Comment: Have a look at https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8446#section-5 that explains how TLS handles records (messages). Besides that, your question is offtopic here as not related to programming.